# Show screens of AWS Device Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

Is there any way to show the screens of Devices from Device Farm without using AWS websites? 
I didn't find any way to do it through Apis. Besides, Is there any chance to beset those screens to a JSP website? I found that they use canvas to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using AWS Device Farm. Currently, we only support showing the screen through run result and remote access.

We will add the feature request to our backlog.

Thanks again for your suggestions.

Best,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Using the list-artifacts CLI[1] command you can get the Files, logs, and screenshots of a run[2].

```
aws devicefarm --list-artifacts --arn <runArn> --type <FILE,SCREENSHOT,LOG> --region us-west-2
```

The list-artifacts command will return a presigned-url which you can use to download the files/logs/screenshots.

To get the run arn you can use the CLI command list-runs:

```
aws devicefarm --list-runs --arn <projectArn> --region us-west-2
```

To get the project arn you can use the list-projects command:

```
aws devicefarm --list-projects --region us-west-2
```

I haven't found anything for list the videos that appear, but I hope this helps.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/list-artifacts.html

Best Regards

James